# Object to database with PDO, is it possible?

Tags: php, pdo

I'm using PDO's fetch_class feature to retrieve data from my database row into object, It's pretty convenient, but how can I do to do the opposite (object to database row) ? without using serialization of course.

Comment: No, the opposite way isn't intended in PDO. That's where the many ActiveRecord libraries come into play. Maybe someone can recommend a simple variant here..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

without using an ORM, you have to create your own save method.

Bye.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't used PDO before, I assume the fetch's contents are stored as $object->Key?

You'd have to write an update method/function

$sql = "UPDATE `table` SET `fieldone` = '$object->fieldone',`fieldtwo` = '$object->fieldtwo' WHERE `id` = $object->id"

mysql_query($sql);

etc.